# What is the windows batch command to remove a path regardless it is file or folder?

Tags: file, command-line, batch-file, directory

Let's say we have a file or a folder named `c:\temp` and we need to remove it if it exists.

What is the command to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Err... why not do both? :)

```
rd /q /s c:\temp
del /q c:\temp
```

One of them will succeed if `C:\temp` is either a file or a folder and the other one will fail. If both fails, it means that it couldn't be deleted or not found. You can even make it a batch file if you don't want to type both commands in all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Err, have you tried

```
rd c:\temp /q /s
```

Comment: @BugFinder I think `rd` is not applicable for files

Comment: the /s does, its a little like the old deltree.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry. But how can we do it quietly?

Comment: Thats what /q does. It doesnt ask

Comment: I've tried and the command fails to remove a file `temp` stored at c:\temp using your command BugFinder. It thinks `temp` is a folder

Comment: Well, it would only fail if something was still in use. Which would apply to anything. It more than certainly works - I ran it on a test directory

Comment: @BugFinder Then you should create a file named `tmp` without extension stored at `c:`. You'll see my error.

Comment: I did. As I said, mine deleted. As I said, only reason it is likely to fail would be files in use. What exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\>rmdir /?
Removes (deletes) a directory.

RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path

    /S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
            in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
            tree.

    /Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S
```

Comment: I have similar comment to BugFinder answer since yours is similar to his.

Comment: @Nam Gi VU: I have updated your question to make clear you want to delete a file, not a folder

Comment: I want to delete either a file or a folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is `del c:\temp`. Sorry I thought it was only used for files and not applicable for folders

Comment: It is applicable for folders but it doesn't delete the folder itself (if `c:\temp` is a folder, that is). And it doesn't remove the subfolders either, only clears them from files.